# A space in front of column in table when created from Laravel migration

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, database-migration

Does anyone run into an issue like me, have extra spaces when I created a table via Laravel migration?

And I'd re-ran couples of time for this migration file and still created extra spaces.

My environment.

- Laravel 5.6
- PHP 7.2
- MySQL 5.7.23

Here are my pictures and migration content.

[image]

[image]

```
Schema::create('plugin_packages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->char('id', 36)->primary();
            $table->char('plugin_id', 36)->nullable();
            $table->char('plugin_package_device_model_id', 36)->nullable();
            $table->char('plugin_package_os_version_id', 36)->nullable();
            $table->string('version_number');
            $table->string('file');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->foreign('plugin_id')->references('id')->on('plugins')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('plugin_package_device_model_id', 'ppdm_id_foreign')->references('id')->on('plugin_package_device_models')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('plugin_package_os_version_id', 'ppov_id_foreign')->references('id')->on('plugin_package_os_versions')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Thank you.

------2019.03.21 updated-------

Got `\u0096\u0096` in front of `plugin_package_os_version_id` column.

```
[{"id":"14f0c766-341c-4262-9a33-0b8fc3063cad","plugin_id":"b3f09e90-cd8b-4e18-9b5e-c9176a5ea898","plugin_package_device_model_id":"a7a630e3-3fac-40c3-b3ed-61d54eb91d6f","\u0096\u0096plugin_package_os_version_id":"623eaf52-09dd-4837-aa9e-79e4f930d654","version_number":"1.0.1","file":"uploads\/application-x-dosexec\/2019-03-12\/FECEdgeServiceSETUP_3484fe18556c19479f8b6caf5c60ec98.exe","created_at":"2019-03-21 14:12:43","updated_at":"2019-03-21 14:12:43","deleted_at":null}]
```

------2019.03.21 updated 2-------

If I change from

`$table->char('plugin_package_os_version_id', 36)->nullable();`

to

`$table->char('ppov_id', 36)->nullable();`

It works as expected.

As an image is shown:

[image]

still cannot be identified where it caused the issue.

-----2019.03.21 update 3-------

Whole content of the migration file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePluginPackagesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('plugin_packages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->char('id', 36)->primary();
            $table->char('plugin_id', 36)->nullable();
            $table->char('plugin_package_device_model_id', 36)->nullable();
            $table->char('plugin_package_os_version_id', 36)->nullable();
            $table->string('version_number');
            $table->string('file');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->foreign('plugin_id')->references('id')->on('plugins')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('plugin_package_device_model_id', 'ppdm_id_foreign')->references('id')->on('plugin_package_device_models')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('plugin_package_os_version_id', 'ppov_id_foreign')->references('id')->on('plugin_package_os_versions')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('plugin_packages');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to run these following commands in your terminal:

1. `composer dump-autoload`
2. `php artisan config:cache`
3. `php artisan migrate:fresh`

Comment: sorry late reply, issue still remain

Comment: can you post the whole `class` in your migration?